# Como bloquear caracteres especiais em campo

Tags: javascript, html

Como não permitir que o usuário insira caracteres especiais tais como `*-/+.,:;[]{}ªº^~?<>` no campo da pergunta?

Comment: acredito que no front-end é muito manipulável essa validação, não?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Se você deseja fazer uma validação simples apenas para auxiliar o usuário no *client-side*, você pode utilizar o **`pattern`**.

Ele é um atributo HTML5 bem fácil de mexer, [aqui](http://wbruno.com.br/html/validando-formularios-apenas-com-html5/) tem alguns exemplos que solucionam o seu problema por exemplo, habilitando apenas letras, letras e números, etc.

Exemplo para letras e números:

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">
```

E o melhor é que é suportado por vários browser segundo o [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern).

---

Agora a validação dos dados, eu recomendo que você faça no *server-side*. Por exemplo com PHP você pode usar o **`preg_match`**:

```
$pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9]';
if (preg_match($pattern, $email)){return true;}
```

Você pode passar diretamente:

```
if (preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9])/", $email)){return true;}
```

Isso fará com que apenas sejam aceitos caracteres do tipo letra e número.

Comment: coloque codigo na resposta. Evite confiar em link externo

Comment: Complementada a resposta Daniel...

Comment: se puder, complete com suporte mais confiavel a browsers antigos...  IE7 , por exemplo, não suporta. Não é recomendável confiar nos recursos HTML5 caso queira atingir um público geral.

Comment: +1 pela recomendação de validar no lado do servidor. Embora as outras respostas estejam corretas no sentido literal, validar só no cliente sem revalidar no servidor é inútil do ponto de vista da segurança.

Answer (score 14):

Fiz desta forma, ele permitirá apenas letras e números:

```js
       document.getElementById("teste").onkeypress = function(e) {
         var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
         if ("1234567890qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM".indexOf(chr) < 0)
           return false;
       };
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="teste" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use o patterns para o HTML 5.

Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" />
```

Comment: se o cliente nao tem html5, como faz?

Comment: Com Javascript, como o Gabriel Rodrigues mostrou, ou alguma lib JS.

Comment: coloque na sua resposta..

Comment: se for resolver no js, torna sem sentido o recurso patern html5..  ainda nao eh seguro confiar e tais recursos, infelizmente

Comment: [No caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=pattern) a pessoa pode ver quais browsers suportam o atributo pattern e decidir se quer ou não usar. Essa decisão cabe ao desenvolvedor e depende do projeto. @DanielOmine

Comment: isso é óbvio..  faltou no mínimo, ressalvas na respostas referente ao uso

Comment: Exatamente, cada um escolhe a melhor opção, se for analisar falar de melhor approach falaríamos de fazer a validação no lado do servidor dependendo da arquitetura server-side com client-side. A pergunta foi simples, e acredito que soluções simples é sempre a melhor escolha.

Comment: entendo, mas não convence

Comment: @DanielOmine, quando tem mais de um usuário nos comentários, é necessário usar o `@nome`, senão você fica falando sozinho ou dá impressão que não quer dialogar...

Comment: entendo, apenas achei desnecessário pois o post foi logo em seguido ao do guiandmag.. por lógica dá para entender que foi uma resposta a ele, mas ele sequer responder.. Não quer dialogar. Então para evitar incomodar achei melhor respeitar a vontade dele em não responder..

Comment: Mas enfim, eu tentei dialogar aqui nos comentarios para decidir se devo ou não negativar a resposta dele.. esse foi o intuito. Discordo da resposta da forma como ele postou. Coloquei o que eu penso e as justificativas dele não me convenceram. Não respondem nada.  Por isso decido negativar, infelizmente.

Comment: @DanielOmine, muito estranho, pois falei sobre ser o mais simples possível na resposta e esse foi o motivo de eu ter respondido com a solução mais simples. Mas não sei se você consegue interpretar, pois acredito que ali teria acabado a discussão. Sobre o seu negativo, é uma opção da plataforma, pois em momento algum eu provi minha resposta pra você.